# Prime ideals in univariate polynomial rings 

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, reference-request

I'm looking for a textbook reference of the following elementary fact (a reference for an excercise in a textbook is also welcome):

Let $R$ be a commutative ring and let $\mathfrak{p}$ be a prime ideal of $R$. An ideal $P \trianglelefteq R[X]$ with $P \cap R = \mathfrak{p}$ is prime iff $P = \mathfrak{p}R[X]$ or if $P$ is maximal in $\lbrace I \trianglelefteq R[X] \mid I \cap R = \mathfrak{p} \rbrace$.

Comment: In the meanwhile I found a reference, though not textbook, in "Ferrero: Prime ideals in polynomial rings in several indeterminates. Proc. Amer. Math. Soc. 125(1997), 67-74", Lemma 1.6. Also note that part of the result generalizes to: If $R \le S$ are comm. rings, $\mathfrak{p} \subseteq R$ prime, then the max. ideals $P \subseteq S$ with $P \cap R = \mathfrak{p}$ are prime. 

Comment: BTW: Is there a possibilty, to prevent that an old question is shown up automatically by "MathOverflow" ? 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am pretty sure this is an exercise in Atiyah-McDonald.

**EDIT** I just looked, and Exercises 2-5 in the first chapter have very similar statements, but not exactly the statement you are looking for...

Comment: I just checked the exercises in Atiyah-McDonald but didn't find it. Maybe I've overlooked it. Though, thanks. 

Comment: How is this an 'answer'?  A comment, sure, but an answer?

Comment: @Jacques, the question asked for a textbook reference, and Igor responded with a textbook reference. How is that not an answer? What would be necessary to qualify as an answer? 

Comment: @Gerry, interesting point.  I was picturing a textbook which contains a proof of this elementary fact as an answer, not one which merely repeated the statement as being true.  

Comment: @Jacques, OP specifically wrote, "a reference for an exercise in a textbook is also welcome." 